# How to calculate datetime interval

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, intervals

Wonder how to calculate de interval between this datetime. I've been trying Datetime_diff() function in SQL Bigqury but unsucessfuly.

| started_at | ended_at |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-04-26 17:45:00 UTC | 2020-04-26 18:12:00 UTC |
| 2020-04-17 17:08:00 UTC | 2020-04-17 17:17:00 UTC |
| 2020-04-01 17:54:00 UTC | 2020-04-01 18:08:00 UTC |

I would like to add a new column with the DURATION of this time travels.

Comment: can you post your query and the result you got vs the result you'd like to see?

Comment: Actually i just made it: `SELECT started_at, ended_at,
date_diff(ended_at, started_at, minute) as duration_minutes FROM table`--this was my last query--. Thank's for your repply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`started_at` and `ended_at` looks TIMESTAMP type, so use TIMESTAMP_DIFF() like below.

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (   
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-04-26 17:45:00 UTC' started_at, TIMESTAMP '2020-04-26 18:12:00 UTC' ended_at UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-04-17 17:08:00 UTC', '2020-04-17 17:17:00 UTC' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-04-01 17:54:00 UTC', '2020-04-01 18:08:00 UTC'
)
SELECT TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at,MINUTE) duration FROM sample_data;
```

[image]

If it's STRING type by any chance, cast it as TIMESTAMP like below instead.

```sql
TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP(ended_at), TIMESTAMP(started_at), MINUTE)
```

Comment: Yes, it's TIMESTAMP. It worked perfectly, thank's for sharing!